# If $\textrm{E}[Q|P] = 3P+7$, $\textrm{E}[P]=2$ and $\textrm{E}[P^2]=8$ what is $\textrm{E}[PQ]$, can this be solved?

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I'm not sure if this can be solved, I've used law of iterated Expectations to get $\textrm{E}[Q]$ but I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, multiply the first equation by $P$:
$$PE[Q|P] = 3P^2 + 7P$$
But we know that $PE[Q|P] = E[PQ|P]$, so now we have $$E[PQ|P] = 3P^2 + 7P$$
and we get the answer by taking the expectation in the last equation.

Comment: how do we know PE[Q|P]=E[PQ|P]? @Michh

Comment: This is because $P$ is $\sigma(P)$-measurable. More generally, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and if $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, then $E[YZ|\mathcal{F}] = YE[Z|\mathcal{F}]$.